# Unable to get results from MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm unable to get results from a MySQL query in PHP. I've tried `get_result()` and `bind_param()`. However, this ends up breaking my script and I'm unable to echo any of the results for testing.

My table has three columns: username, password, and email.

```
$usernameprep = $conn->prepare("SELECT 1, password FROM `table` WHERE username=?");
$usernameprep->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$usernameprep->execute();
$usernameprep->bind_results($userexists, $userpass);
$usernameprep->close();
```

What I've tried:

- `get_result()` and `bind_param()`
- putting `bind_param()` after AND before `execute()`
- echoing `$user` and `$userpass`, only for my script to break afterwards
- searching endless **StackOverflow** questions and none of them work for me

Note: I am used to SQLite3, so I'm still getting used to how MySQL works.

**UPDATE:** adding code for my connection for reference

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'database';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Connection Error, please try again.";
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to be using MySqli,  MySql is pretty much outdated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: What’s MySqli? For some reference, I’m using MAMP with MySQL for a CST class

Comment: It's the updated MySql,  If your server has MySqli installed in it all you have to do is re-write your connection and the code you have will probably work.. Please post your code for your connection.

Comment: You need to fetch the results, which is the step you are missing. Use: `while ($usernameprep->fetch()) { ... }`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: @Martin Parkin You are correct he needs to that as well, but that does not explain why his code is breaking.  When he post his connection code we will know more.

Comment: So you are using a MySqli connection.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I tried the while loop with fetch already and attempted to echo $userexists and $userpass like they did with printf. Still broke my code

Comment: What does _broke my code_ mean exactly? What error message are you getting? I suspect you simply mean that no result is being returned

Comment: Thing is I'm not getting any errors, or at least... I'm not sure how to check for errors on Eclipse. My current bottom tabs are: Problems, Tasks, Servers. The code is being run through a localhost webpage.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that your SQL code returns no results, and that is the problem you are experiencing

Comment: Thing is I'm not sure why it wouldn't return any results. I have one complete row in the table, and I'm sure the username is exactly perfect. I even tried a query directly through myPhpAdmin and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

```
echo 'Here is your post data.  Make sure you have your username.<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';


$query = "SELECT password FROM `table` WHERE username=?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn)); //This will show you your errors after the execute();
$results = $stmt->get_result();

if($results->num_rows !== 0){

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

  $data[] = array(

    'userexists' => 1,
    'userpass'  => $row['password']

  );

}

}else{

  echo "Your query failed to find any data.";

}

$stmt->close();

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is your data:<br>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Seems like it worked! But what exactly did you do differently? When I tried get_result() it wouldn't work at all

Comment: Also would this work if I used bind_params()? I just don't like using get_result() with multiple results as I find PHP arrays to be a bit messy

Comment: What do you want as a result?  Do you prefer objects?

Comment: I'd prefer what I had earlier with $userexists and $userpass. As I said, I'm not used to MySql at all. Thank you for being patient, by the way

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. It's correctly posting the $_POST data, but not even echoing the actual $data

Comment: My output:

Here is your post data. Make sure you have your username.
Array
(
    [username] => username
    [password] => password
)

Comment: What are the values they are suppose to be?

Comment: The username and a crypted password. The stuff earier is just the $_POST data. It’s supposed to also echo the $data but it breaks once I try to, meaning it probably has nothing in it

Comment: If it had nothing it would have said your query failed to find any data.

Comment: Hey sorry for late response @Joseph_J. For some reason it's not recognizing the user that I KNOW exists... It keeps saying that the user doesn't exist. Do you want me to post my (almost) full code? I still think the issue is something with the query and getting the data, though. I can do my queries through phpMyAdmin just fine, but it breaks when in a PHP script

Comment: Did some more testing with some echoes. The script is breaking exactly on the execute() line. Any idea why?

Comment: Oddly enough that was only a temporary thing... After testing if the execute works with a variable it magically started working again... This whole thing is confusing tf out of me

Comment: I did some more testing, and I'm able to INSERT just fine, but SELECT for some reason won't work at all

Comment: When you say breaks, what do you mean?  Are you getting any errors?  I would make sure you have your php error reporting turned on. I would also read on how to display your mysqli errors.  Those error messages can give you some good insight into what's going on.